# Creating an array of other objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is something like this possible:

```
function FooClass()
{
   var barsArray=new Array();
   var index=0;

   function addBar()
   {
     barsArray[index]=new BarClass(index);
   }
}

function BarClass()
{
   var myIndex;
   function BarClass(index)
   {
      myIndex=index;
   }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, Objects and Arrays are, for all intents and purposes, the same thing in JavaScript.

Comment: can you use for (x=1; x< obj.length; x++) to loop through the elements of an object like you can in an array?

Comment: You *could* if you defined your own length property and kept it up to date. You would also need to have the correct "numeric" properties (all properties are really strings, but strings that look like numbers are treated specially). Don't do it though, since Arrays are optimized for faster access and update "length" automatically to cover all the numeric properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inferring that you want to have a Foo object, and that Foo object should contain an array of Bar objects.  Each Bar object should know its array index within its parent Foo object.

If that is an accurate description, then try this:

```
function BarClass(idx) {
    this.myIndex = idx;
}

function FooClass(howMany) {
    this.barsArray = [];

    for (var x = 0; x < howMany; x++) {
        this.barsArray[x] = new BarClass(x);
    }

}

var foo = new FooClass(5);
// foo.barsArray[0].myIndex === 0
// foo.barsArray[1].myIndex === 1
// foo.barsArray[2].myIndex === 2
// foo.barsArray[3].myIndex === 3
// foo.barsArray[4].myIndex === 4
// foo.constructor === 'FooClass'
// foo.barsArray[0].constructor === 'BarClass'
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite (actually it compiles, but probably doesn't do what you intended).

I'm assuming you want to create a `FooClass` class with an `addBar` method that appends a `BarClass` object to it's `barsArray` member.

The `addBar` function is just a local variable inside the `FooClass` function/constructor. To make it accessible from outside the constructor, you need to assign it to `this.addBar`. Other than remembering to increment `index`, that's all you would need to change in `FooClass`.

For the `BarClass` class, remember that a "class" is really just a constructor function. You don't need to (and can't) a separate constructor. `BarClass` would just be a single function that takes an index and assigns it to `this.myIndex`.

```
function FooClass()
{
   // use this.barsArray = [], etc if you want them to be publically available
   var barsArray=[]; // It's usually better to use "[]" instead of "new Array()"
   var index=0;

   this.addBar = function() {
     barsArray[index]=new BarClass(index);
     index++;
   }
}

function BarClass(index)
{
   this.myIndex=index;
}
```

If you change `barsArray` and `index` to be properties instead of local variables ("this.barsArray = [];" and "this.index = 0"), you can put `addBar` in `FooClass.prototype` and there will only be one instance of the function:

```
function FooClass()
{
   this.barsArray=[];
   this.index=0;
}

FooClass.prototype.addBar = function() {
   this.barsArray[this.index]=new BarClass(this.index);
   this.index++;
};
```